# How to calculate a return of investment with inflation added?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, svelte, calculation

I'd like to ask someone who is more skillful than me. I need to calculate a return on investment but I need to add inflation for each year.

Example:
I made a purchase of some assets that generate/save money (solar power/car for job/ tools). Purchasing price of that asset was 20 000$ and generates 2350$ each year. In the simple model, the asset is paid off in **8,5 years** (20000/2350) but it doesn't count with inflation which can be 3% each year on average. I tried to find a solution but I was able to figure it out only for the first year because for the second year the calculation is not from 2350$ but from 2420$ (2350 + 3%) and so on... **the desired result is to calculate years of the inflation-adjusted return.**

My effort so far:

```
<script>
    let price = 20000;
    let gain_year = 2350; 
    let inflation = 3;
    
 $: return_in_years = price /gain_year;
    
// this is only for the first year
// $: inflation_calc = (gain_year/100)*inflation;
    
</script>

<label for="gain_year">Gain in one year</label>
<input id="gain_year" type="number" bind:value={gain_year} />

<label for="price">Price</label>
<input id="price" type="number" bind:value={price} />

<label for="inflation">Inflation</label>
<input id="inflation" type="number" bind:value={inflation} />

<div>
  Return in how many years: {return_in_years.toFixed(1)}
</div>
```

Thank you guys for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an expert in finance but I think this might work for you. Please apply only the concept here. Your actual code will look different from this.

```js
// your inputs
let price = 20000;
let gain_year = 2350; 
let inflation = 3;
// result in years
let years = 0;
// loop for each year until the invesment is returned
while (price > 0){
  // apply inflation except the first year
  if (years > 0) gain_year += gain_year * inflation/100;
  // price is more than gain this year
  if (price >= gain_year){
    // update full year and price according to the gain this year
    years++;
    price -= gain_year;
  }
  // price is less than gain this year
  else {
    // update year according to the portion of the price and gain this year
    years += price / gain_year;
    // set price to 0 so it ends
    price = 0;
  }
  // result
  console.log(price, years, gain_year);
}
```

Comment: This solution works fine but only for static statements/variables. I can't figure out how to do it with reactive variables "$:" When I declare variables in a reactive format and try to put the price for calculation every time when I add a numeral into the price input the loop is activated (it loops 4x ) and the result of return years is 4 times bigger. I tried the 'do while' function for only one loop but the result in years is NaN, then I tried to add '&& variable > 1000' into a declaration of the 'while' function but it is not a solution either it limits function only for 4 digits of price.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a loop that runs the number of years of inflation you want to calculate. Inside the loop, do the normal calculation for inflation rate as you are doing now for the first year, but update the gain_year variable with the result each time just before the loop ends. Next time the loop runs, it will use the result from the last loop run in the calculation.

Comment: I tried something similar but problem was that I don't know the number of years of return or years of inflation. I can't get along from 'price /gain_year'. I mean the return without inflation can be 8 years (that's easy) but with inflation can be the return 7 or 6 years so the number 8 is not information to build on. Or I don't get your answer.